# Pine Editor Exit condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to build a backtest strategy on Forex Market, my shorts and my longs entry are fine, but the exits are tricky.
I want to exit ONLY IF my targets (profit or loss, in pips) are hit, and with no pyramiding (trying different settings, nothing's change), if an order is open, nothing should happen until those targets are hit, but he closed them as well when there is a longcondition (or shortcondition if I'm in long) true.

Try everything in my mind and research, strategy.exit, .close, .close_all, entry_rules etc. etc.

And I can't find a way to do it. This can eventually work using average_price but it's in % of price action (not very useful in forex, every pairs have different percent of price value) and I want it in pips for now.

Also I wish to add a Break Even function, who put my SL on my entry point at 1% gain, Risking 1% Per trade, can't set up this for now but I set up this for 25 pips (250 points) SL and 75 pips for TP, so I wish it securitize my order on my entry when the price is 25 pips greater then the entry price.

If anyone has ideas, I'll be glad and grateful!

```
strategy(title="FOREXBOT1", overlay=true, pyramiding =1,  close_entries_rule="ANY")
accountBalance  = input(title="Account Balance", type=input.float, defval=1000.0)
accountCurrency = input(title="Account Currency", type=input.string, defval="EUR", options=["AUD", "CAD", "CHF", "EUR", "GBP", "JPY", "NZD", "USD"])
riskPerTrade    = input(title="Risk Per Trade 0.01", type=input.float, defval=1.0)
stopSize        = input(title="Stop Loss Size (250)", type=input.float, defval=10.0)

// Source

src = input(defval=close, title="Source")

// Smooth Average Range

smoothrng(x, t, m) =>
    wper = t * 2 - 1
    avrng = ema(abs(x - x[1]), t)
    smoothrng = ema(avrng, wper) * m
    smoothrng
smrng = smoothrng(src, per, mult)

// Range 

rngfilt(x, r) =>
    rngfilt = x
    rngfilt := x > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? x - r < nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x - r : 
       x + r > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x + r
    rngfilt
filt = rngfilt(src, smrng)

// Filter Direction

upward = 0.0
upward := filt > filt[1] ? nz(upward[1]) + 1 : filt < filt[1] ? 0 : nz(upward[1])
downward = 0.0
downward := filt < filt[1] ? nz(downward[1]) + 1 : filt > filt[1] ? 0 : nz(downward[1])

// Bands

hband = filt + smrng
lband = filt - smrng

//Break Outs

longCond = bool(na)
shortCond = bool(na)
longCond := ((src > filt) and (src > src[1]) and (upward > 0)) or ((src > filt) and (src < src[1]) and (upward > 0)) 
shortCond := ((src < filt) and (src < src[1]) and (downward > 0)) or ((src < filt) and (src > src[1]) and (downward > 0))

CondIni = 1
CondIni := longCond ? 1 : shortCond ? -1 : CondIni[1]
longCondition = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1
shortCondition = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1

// Entry / Exits

strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when = shortCondition, comment="Short entry")
strategy.exit( id = "Short", profit = 750, loss = 250, comment="Shortout" )


strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = longCondition, comment="Long entry")
strategy.exit( id = "Long", profit = 750, loss = 250, comment="Longout" )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, this can help:

```
...
longCondition = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1 and strategy.position_size == 0
shortCondition = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1 and strategy.position_size == 0
...
```